# What's the behavior of this code's loop?

Tags: c, assembly, arm

```
int main() 
{
    int i;
    int v = 5;
    for (i = 0; v; i++)
    {
        v &= (v - 1);
        printf("%d\n", v);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I know it will exit after two iterations, but why?

Comment: when does v become false, i.e. 0?

Comment: Add some more prints and explain it yourself

Comment: the debugger is also your friend. Here's a chance to use it on a simple example and then get used to use it all the time.

Comment: hint... 5 is 101 in binary, and 4 is 100 in binary. so 5 & 4 (bitwise and) is 4

Comment: Yes, at v=0, how it is handled internally?if let's suppose it runs on some ARM processor, what internal factors will make this for loop stop after v=0.

Comment: Guys, i know what will happen to code, otherwise it will be very stupid top ask, my question is, what factor will make this for loop stop? as after preprocessor, the bool file which implicitly included in c compiler, gcc for instance, when this code flashed to some ARM MCU, how it will end the loop during runtime? does some machine op-codes does this,or how?i do not get any point in the understanding.

Comment: I see you have shot down several answers which seem correct. You need to ask a different question if people are not giving you the answer you're looking for.

Comment: You should make the question clearer, if what you actually want to know is what machine instruction causes the change on flow, you should state that. It is not obvious from the question

Comment: this would be much more suited for a `while` loop. `i` is useless, and will probably get optimized out anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The loop has a counter (`i`) that starts at zero. It runs the lines within in while it stop condition is not met (i.e., while `v` is `different than`0`).

In each iteration, `v` receives the result of a bitwise `AND` (`&`) between `v` and `v-1`.

Then, the value of `v` is printed at the end of each iteration.

If you add the statement below in just after `for (i = 0; v; i++) {`, you will be able to see what is being done in each iteration:

`printf("i=%d, v=%d, v-1=%d, v & (v-1) = %d\n", i, v, v-1, v & (v - 1));`

Output:

> i=0, v=5, v-1=4, v & (v-1) = 4
>
> 4
>
> i=1, v=4, v-1=3, v & (v-1) = 0
>
> 0

You can try it online [here](http://ideone.com/glm7QA).

In the 1st iteration, `v = 5 & (5 - 1) = 5 & (4) = 4`. Since `v != 0`, the loop continues.

In the 2nd iteration, `v = 4 & (4 - 1) = 4 & (3) = 0`. Since `v == 0`, the loop stops.

As I stated in my comments, in a lower lewel, *"there is a comparison being made, probably by a BNZ (branch if not zero) ASM instruction. IF the zero flag is not set, then continue; ELSE, branch. You can find more detailed info [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFFHBB.html) and [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABEHFEF.html)."*

Comment: Hey Marcelo, thanks, but what you have explained is something for c-toddler. My question is different. I know what will happen to code, otherwise it will be very stupid top ask, i am concerned with what factor will make this for loop stop? as after preprocessor, the bool file which implicitly included in c compiler, gcc for instance, when this code flashed to some ARM MCU, how it will end the loop during runtime? does some machine op-codes does this,or how?i do not get any point in the understanding.

Comment: You explicitly asked "_why the loop exits after two iterations_". I answered "_because in the second iteration the stop condition is met_". There is no rocket science behind that, just a comparison between integers. If you need more details, please edit your question and provide the necessary information.

Comment: As you said, "Since v == 0, the loop stops" Yeah my precise question is "WHY DOES IT SO?", which instruction set does this? or to be more precise, does this is done on compiler end or to the machine instruction set end? can anyone explain?

Comment: Hey, "There is no rocket science behind that, just a comparison between integers"...there is no comparison being occur. Just the "v" state is monitored. after being to zero it stops the loop, so i need to know why? and sorry for the wrong start of the question, i may have not explained in brief.

Comment: Yes, there is a comparison being made, probably by a BNZ (branch if not zero) ASM instruction. IF the zero flag is not set, then continue; ELSE, branch. You can find more detailed info [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABFFHBB.html) and [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dui0552a/BABEHFEF.html).

Comment: @JohnD the second of the three sections in a `for` loop control, is evaluated as `true` or `false`. In C, any non-0 value evaluates to `true`, and `0` evaluates to `false`. So `v` is `true` until it has the value `0`. The expression `v` is implicit code for the explicit `v != 0`.

Comment: Hey Marcelo, thanks for the input. I can accept your comment for the understanding of my question.

Comment: @JohnD, I've just edited my answer with those details.

Comment: @JohnD, do not forget to accept/upvote the answer if you think it could help other users in SO.

Answer (score 4):

You need to look at the binary representation and remember that `&` is a bit-wise and-operator:

```
v = 5 = 101b
// First loop
v = 5 & (5-1) = 5 & 4 = 101b & 100b = 100b = 4
// Second loop
v = 4 & (4-1) = 4 & 3 = 100b & 011b = 000b = 0
// No more loops
```

Comment: Hey, thanks but i am aware of this. I got my some reasonable input in the comments below by @Marcelo Vinícius

Comment: So to summarize, `v & (v-1)` clears the lowest set bit.  The [wikipedia article for x86's bit-manipulation instruction set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Sets#BMI1_.28Bit_Manipulation_Instruction_Set_1.29) has C expressions + English descriptions for all of them, so it's actually useful as a reference for just that, even if you don't care how it could compile on x86 with `-mbmi`.

Comment: Oh great..thanks Peter.